# Flow - How can I type an object that consists of objects nested within it

Tags: javascript, flowtype

How would I properly type the following (not correctly typed) function?

```
function myfunction<O, T:{ +[string]: any => O }>(inputObject: T): { ...O } {
    let ret = {};

    Object.values(inputObject).forEach(x => {
            const out = inputObject[x]();
            ret = {
                ...ret,
                ...out
            }
    });

    return ret;
}
```

I want to be able to take in an input such as

```
let inputObj = {
    call1: () => ({
        response1: {
        }
    }),
    call2: () => ({
        response2: {
        }
    })
}

myfunction(inputObj)
```

And get the output type which in this case would be

```
type outputObj = {
    response1: {},
    response2: {}
}
```

I've tried combinations of the utility functions such as $ObjMap<>, but the problem is that I don't know how to make a new object that raises the nested keys up to a higher level.

This is a slightly contrived function. Ultimately I'm trying to type a React HOC that injects extra props into a component, but the injected props are a function of the input to the HOC that take the shape of the `inputObject` specified above.

Comment: Good question! You might want to look at the example of $ObjMap in the flow docs. It includes an example similar to what you're trying to do. I couldn't get Flow to get closer than `{| response1: {} |} | {| response2: {} |}` when I gave this a try earlier today.

Comment: I was able to get that using `$Values<T>` or `$ElementType<T, $Keys<T>>` (same result as far as I can tell). If only there was a way to combine the members of a union.

Comment: @JamesKraus I know, I feel like `{...$Values<$ObjMap<O, ExtractReturnType>>}` gets so close but not quite there. I'm starting to think that it's not currently possible as of version 0.73.0.

Comment: Probably not. You may or may not be able to get help in IRC or on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I noticed a GitHub issue where someone is asking about a $Reduce function that sounds like it could be used for this case. https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6381

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt where I got it to `{| response1: {} |} | {| response2: {} |}`. It doesn't really answer your question, but maybe you or someone else can improve it.

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAogHsATgQwMbAEoWAV0QOwBVxoBeKAHgDUA+ACjoEopSaornX2AobgMxz50ASwD2+KAFsQAocDH4KAeQBcUAN4BtANYQQagM5Jh+AOYBdNQDFBI8QF8a3KFDomwOYEoBGAKwjoakqMauoAPgB0UQAkVMgANjgQBhTRPr4AsshgygA0sAgo6Fi4BMSQNDRh9hrOUHUuiNh4EukBwBG6IAZu+B5efu2MDS6jLhFNACY4qBAMaKj52pxsbegRyAYGwqb4dAv57p5rwDrmTIz56vbDY-a88dhQRwO+LLVjqAnxAIxqTCw2HR1CMxk0DGBxAYIH8PmN4d54sgABZqADkfFEojRoNG9zulxGX3i8QATP8Vq4QfDRuDIfhoeS4TSXJIIKioGjvMhEDiWVB8XjhvduKBIFBRJ5+ul3tTacl6dDYddciM6VCIEzrtxBWNRSQoAB3RDiUxKKXHPyytUKjUAFlC9lVutG3FQUOAUGAyWAP3e0lkdj2L3Sw3dDM93qMTMlwGlVvIAds8nEvXjvmGAHpM+GjF6fUzjabzXHLW9EzJkwo02Xbq7s1AAHJYybxEymKA8yX4SZG4TAZFe5HQMXJfXirJgSCTdLKNjkNJ+Sd5ApINCYZplEhOUf5owAfUk70n09no9EfGefTLO4NMEebPwwAMSj4s6U86g0XvEEfwHKEAUCeEAzn4c75NEADSegpB+t7ilGwD7mQsAPhAT4vm+YHnpeIZ+PB0AAIIknE8SYe+n7hFEEQ-n+5FgR+UDVK6u6IfuABu7zEfEpH0b4FA4Ve6ZONwQA))

```
type ExtractReturnType = <V>(() => V) => V

function myfunction<O: {[key: string]: Function}>
  (inputObject: O): {|...$Values<$ObjMap<O, ExtractReturnType>>|} {

    return Object.keys(inputObject)
          .reduce((acc, k) => Object.assign(acc, inputObject[k]()), {})
    }

let inputObj = {
    call1: () => ({
        response1: {
          blah: 'foo'
        }
    }),
    call2: () => ({
        response2: {
          meh: 'bar'
        }
    })
}

type outputObj = {
    response1: {},
    response2: {}
}

type wrongOutputObj = {
    response4: {},
}

const test1 = myfunction(inputObj)
const test2: outputObj = myfunction(inputObj)
//const test2: wrongOutputObj = myfunction(inputObj)
```